# Array of Strings in C obtained by reading a file and displaying it

Tags: c

I wanna store an array of Strings and display it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    int i = 0;
    char* array[200000];
    char prod [10]; 

    FILE * fp = fopen ("arrayValues.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(prod, 10, fp) != NULL) {

        array[i] = strtok(prod, "\n\r");
        i++;

    }

    fclose(fp); 


    for (i = 0; array[i] ; i++) {

        printf("%s  %d\n", array[i], i);

    }



}
```

but the output is only the last line of the file im working with x times.
Suggestions?

Comment: Note there is no conventional line-ending format that uses `\n\r`. Windows uses `\r\n` and *nix use `\n`

Comment: How does `arrayvalues.txt` look like? I assume you are trying to load each line in the array.

Comment: You're overwriting `prod` every time you read a line, not making a copy. And `strtok()` just returns a pointer into the string. So all your array elements point to that same string that's being overwritten.

Comment: strtok is going to return a pointer to `prod` and modify the contents of `prod`.  you are always storing prod to array[i].  you are also modifying the contents of `prod` every time inside your while loop via fgets.  thus all the prints will be the same.  also, you don't terminate your last array value with NULL to indicate the end.

Comment: @GovindParmar - True and that's what that parameter is doing he detects both \n and \r so he works in both systems. He doesnt look for \n\r together but divided if this makes sense.

Comment: @balki - Yes, the content does not matter, it is less then 10 chars long tho.

Comment: Try `strdup(strtok(...))` And initialize the array like `char* array[200000] = {0}`

Comment: @MFisherKDX that's right, thank you. I thought he returned a new pointer in memory each time.

Comment: @balki - Yap, allocating memory with strdup solves the problem! Thank you man! My bad

Comment: @balki Why the initialization? strtok puts the '\0' allways in the end

Comment: In the for-loop, you are checking if `array[i]` is NULL. You don't need it if you check for end of strings using a different condition like in the answer. `for(j = 0; j < i ;++j)`

Comment: @GovindParmar - If Im not wrong /r in *nix means new line and /n in windows and I dont want to preserve the new lines, I explained it poorly. Thank you.

Comment: @Barmar - Yap that was the problem, thought strtok generated a new pointer and allocated new memory.

Answer (score 1):

Using your coding style try this (please adjust the hard coded values to your needs)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char array[200000][11];
    char prod [10]; 
    char *ptr;

    memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

    FILE * fp = fopen ("arrayValues.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(prod, 10, fp) != NULL) {

        ptr = strtok(prod, "\n\r");
        snprintf(array[i], sizeof(array[i]) , ptr);
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        i++;

    }

    fclose(fp); 

    printf("============\n");

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++){ 
        printf("%s  %d\n", array[j], j);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: man page says `bzero` is deprecated. `The bzero() function is deprecated (marked  as  LEGACY  in  POSIX.1-2001);  use  memset(3)  in  new  programs.`

Comment: Is using the 2D array more efficient then using an 1D pointer array? Your version is very good, but I wanted to escape the 2D array version.

Comment: `char array[200000][11];` may blow the stack on some OS's and memory models.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True, but so can `char* array[200000]`